# Firebase messaging multiple notification in single request

Tags: firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I must to send multiple notifications with single request using Firebase Messaging. Below is example how i send notification to single user. Any help will be very appreciate.

```
  curl --header "Authorization: key=***********" --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "notification": {
    "title": "FCM Message",
    "body": "This is an FCM Message"
   },
  "to": "********************************************",
   }' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope it will help somebody.

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=***********" --header "Content-Type: 
application/json" -d '{
 "notification": {
   "title": "FCM Message",
   "body": "This is an FCM Message"
 },
 "registration_ids": ["********************************************",
    "*********************************",
    "*********************************"]
 }' https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```